# Set range for input

Tags: html, css

So I want to create a numerical input that only accepts values from -90 to 90.
What I have right now accepts all numerical values, just the arrows don't go past these values. I want a way where you can only type in values between -90 and 90 (inclusive). I'm trying to avoid js with this if possible. Could someone help?

```
<input type="number" id="latitude" placeholder="Enter Your Latitude"min="-90" max="90">
```

Comment: You will have to use javascript. If you want to anything more than that you will have to use it anyways.

Comment: You can still manually enter a number outside the range, but it will be considered invalid during validation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can use :

```
<input type="range" min="-90" max="90" />
```

Your only way would be javascript, the thing with html input types is that, even if you type a string (like "Hello") in that number input, its not gonna stop it from being typed.

Comment: Could you help me with the js code then? I guess I'll have to add that, because if you couldn't already tell by the id, I'm trying to get a latitude input, and I need it to be fairly precise.

Comment: With js you could do it in too many ways based on what you need, and this is not the place for it anyways, what I can tell you however is that if you are ever using the value of this input for anything in js, you can also do the validation as easily, and check if its between the wanted values. however if you only want to submit this form and have nothing to do with the values, your own `min` and `max` wont allow the form to be submitted if the value doesnt fit, so you dont actually need any additional help with that